# Variable in valueSuffix?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible reference a point from a series within the valueSuffix parameter?

I want to include a percentage value within the Suffix by dividing the height of the series 1 column by the height of the series 2 column.

So something like the following:

valueSuffix: ( series[1].max / series[2].max ) + ' %'

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Armin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API states this : [`valueSuffix: String`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.valueSuffix)
Which means the valueSuffix can only be a String. If you want something more complex than a string, consider using [`tooltip.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) instead

Inside the formatter you will have access to the chart as `this.series.chart` and from the chart you can then access any series or any point you may wish to